# Sample size determination for a 4000 population

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, sample-size

I'm trying to determine the sample size to use in a 4000 elements population experiment. To do that, I conduced an experiment in a similar population (50 elements) to compute its standard deviation. The methodology is described below:

- For each element, I have two different solutions (solutions A and B);
- I'm evaluating a particular aspect of this solutions (in this case is the total area of an integrated circuit);
- I find the percentage of optimization in this parameter.

For example, for the 1st experiment I have found this two values: 20um² (solution A) and 15um² (solution B).  So solution B is 25% smaller then A.

Following this methodology, I produced a Table of optimizations. Something like this:

```
 X  | Opt (%)
-------------
 1  |  25
 2  | -10
 3  |  -5
... | ...
50  |  10
```

So I take the mean and the standard deviation of this results and found an optimization of 5% (average) with 22% of standard deviation.

Now I have the formula below to determine the sample size of a 4000 population for a new experiment:
$$
n = Z^2\sigma^2 N/[(N-1)e^2+Z^2 \sigma^2]
$$
Where $n$ is the sample size, $Z$ is related to the confidence, $N$ is the size of the population (4000) and $e$ is the error.

My question is: is that ok to use σ = 22% of my previous experiment? Notice that is a similar population.

Computing n considering Z = 1.645 (confidence of 90%), e = 5% = 0.05, σ = 22% = 0.22 and N = 4000, I found `n = 51,76`. Rounding up, my sample size is 52 for a 4000 population.

Is that ok? Any thoughts?